# java9: IllegalArgumentException using jlink

Tags: java-9, java-platform-module-system, jlink

Im exploring java9 and Im tring to create a custom jre following this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/jlink-in-java-9).
But Im getting IllegalArgumentException.Below is my folder structure after compilation .

```
out
|->moduleA
|    |->module-info.java
|    |->pkg1
|        |->Test.class
|
|->java.base.jmod
```

Im able to run my program with default jre.But when I tried creating custom jre using the following command :**jlink --module-path out --add-modules moduleA,java.base --output customjre**

I get **Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**

Im not sure what Im missing.Any help will be really useful.

Comment: Can you paste the full error message?

Comment: And the details of the tools or the JDK(version etc) would also be good to have in the question.

Comment: @ ZhekaKozlov It is the only message i got in the console

Comment: @nullpointer the jdk version is 9.0.4.

Comment: Do you really have a `module-info.java` in your output folder? You should compile `module-info.java` like any other `*.java` file and have a `module-info.class` in your output folder. And why do you have a `java.base.jmod` in your output folder?

Comment: I suggest to read [the tool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm) instead of some spurious tutorials. You are not supposed to mess around with jdk modules; since your module does already declare all dependencies, `jlink` will know which jdk modules it needs to include…

Comment: I assume it means module-info.class rather than module-info.java, otherwise the error would be "ModuleA not found". I'm 99% sure the issue is that the java.base.jmod has been copied from a JDK 10 (or JDK 11 EA) and he's using JDK 9 jlink.